# How to create a PDFsharp table with dynamic data?

Tags: c#, regex, pdfsharp

I am populating a table in PDFsharp to display chart legend data. I have 14 objects in my list and only 2 are being displayed, and the colors of their rectangles are identical. They each have a unique color to use. How can I get all of them to display correctly?

```
   //Draw the table Row Borders
            xGrap.DrawRectangle(XPens.DarkSeaGreen, XBrushes.DarkSeaGreen, snoColumn); //Use different Color for Colum
            xGrap.DrawRectangle(XPens.DarkSeaGreen, XBrushes.DarkSeaGreen, snoStudentName);

            //Writting Table Header Text
            textformater.DrawString(" Color", tableheader, XBrushes.Black, snoColumn);
            textformater.DrawString(" Subdivision Name", tableheader, XBrushes.Black, snoStudentName);

            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                string colorStr = item.Color;

                Regex regex = new Regex(@"rgb\((?<r>\d{1,3}),(?<g>\d{1,3}),(?<b>\d{1,3})\)");
                Match match = regex.Match(colorStr);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    int r = int.Parse(match.Groups["r"].Value);
                    int g = int.Parse(match.Groups["g"].Value);
                    int b = int.Parse(match.Groups["b"].Value);

                    y = y + 30;
                    XRect snoColumnVal = new XRect(35, y, 60, 25);
                    XRect snoStudentNameVal = new XRect(100, y, 250, 25);

                    var brush = new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(r, g, b));
                    xGrap.DrawRectangle(brush, snoColumnVal);
                    textformater.DrawString(item.Name, bodyfont, XBrushes.Black, snoStudentNameVal);

                };
            };
```

List of objects
[image: pic]

This is the result I am currently getting
[image: picture]

Comment: The first line appears to be Data[0], but the second line is not Data[1]. You have the complete project, you can step through it in debugger, you can see which values you get for r,g,b and how many iterations the foreach loop does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the color string of Data[1] contains a blank (blue has two digits only). Maybe this causes the match to fail and the line is skipped.

As a hack you can try `regex.Match(colorStr.Replace(" ", ""));`. Better modify the regular expression to allow spaces.

You do not show the color string for Savannah.